# Chromecast duplicate connection when one sender connects to custom receiver

Tags: javascript, chromecast, sender, custom-receiver

I've recently started encountering an issue where 2 sender connection events are firing every time only 1 sender connects to my custom receiver. I'm getting the following error in the receiver debug console.

```
cast_receiver.js:37  [  2.456s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Unexpected connected message for already connected sender: 14:client-20839cast_receiver.js:37 Ub
cast_receiver.js:37  [  2.459s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Unexpected sender already registered [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 14:client-20839]cast_receiver.js:37 Ub
cast_receiver.js:37  [  2.460s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Unexpected sender already registered [urn:x-cast:com.massivision.test, 14:client-20839]cast_receiver.js:37 Ub
```

I haven't made any changes to my sender or receiver code for a few weeks then this started happening a day or so ago. I expect this is being caused by a change in the cast_receiver.js. Is anyone else experiencing this same issue?

Comment: What do you see in onSenderConnected() callback?

Comment: I see the same sender with the same id connecting twice when only 1 connects.

Comment: Then there is something strange is going on with your receiver/sender; we don't get that with our senders or receivers. Try using one of our sample sender/receivers and see if you run into the same issue. Also, please provide the complete log to see more of what is going on (turn on debugging)

Comment: I'm getting this as well...